# Measuring maximum memory while capturing stdout in Python using subprocess

Tags: python, memory, subprocess, stdout

Is there a clean way to measure the maximum memory consumption of a subprocess while still capturing stdout (and ideally setting a timeout) using `subprocess` in Python?

Capturing output and setting a timeout can easily done using functions of `subprocess`:

```
output = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, timeout=100)
```

Measuring the maximum allocated memory seems to require polling, i.e. using `psutil` as in this example: [Subprocess memory usage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607391/subprocess-memory-usage-in-python). But this way, capturing stdout would also need to be implemented, which gets messy quickly (`subprocess` starts a new thread for reading stdout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure the max memory consuption of a subprocess and capture stdout by combining `subprocess` and `psutil`.

Use `subprocess.Popen` to start the subprocess. This way you can interact with the subprocess as it runs.
Periodically check the memory usage with `psutil`.

Here's an example implementation I have from a previous project:

```
import subprocess
import psutil
import time

def run_command_with_memory_tracking(cmd, timeout=None):
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    psutil_process = psutil.Process(process.pid)
    
    max_memory = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    output, errors = "", ""

    # polling loop
    while True:
        # measure memory
        current_memory = psutil_process.memory_info().rss
        max_memory = max(max_memory, current_memory)
        
        if timeout and (time.time() - start_time) > timeout:
            process.kill()
            raise TimeoutError(f"Command '{' '.join(cmd)}' timed out after {timeout} seconds")

        if process.poll() is not None:
            break

        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    output, errors = process.communicate()

    return {
        "max_memory": max_memory,
        "stdout": output,
        "stderr": errors
    }

# Test
cmd = ["echo", "Hello, World!"]
result = run_command_with_memory_tracking(cmd, timeout=10)

print(f"Max memory used: {result['max_memory']} bytes")
print(f"Output:\n{result['stdout']}")
print(f"Errors:\n{result['stderr']}")
```

Comment: Small issure with this though: the stdout and stderr buffers are limited, and if it runs full the process is not terminated even if it completes